# Can I catch a rewritten domain name in php and do stuff with it?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have a WordPress website that is hosted using NGINX. I do not have any root access. Their system allows me to point multiple domains to one WordPress site. When you visit the 2nd domain, their hosting rewrites it to the primary domain name. I am unfamiliar with NGINX, but I am assuming it is similar to an Apache rewrite rule.

The only thing I have permission to do is create a custom plugin and install it. So I can use PHP or WordPress' own actions. But I would like to catch when the original request comes through using the 2nd domain so that I can then do stuff.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: You probably can read the $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] variable to get the requested domain. Many other variables at $_SERVER (server and execution environment information) array could be useful to you, so, you can try dumping it to analyze using a simple script with: `<?php echo "<pre>"; var_dump ( $_SERVER); echo "</pre>"; ?>`

Comment: @ErnaniAzevedo By the time the $_SERVER variable is written no trace of the first domain entered is left. The server_name variable shows the domain name being displayed currently, not the one that was rewritten.